# Redirect System.in to swing component

Tags: java, swing, terminal

Hey guys I am making a terminal application using Swing and Apache Commons. I was able to redirect `System.out` and `System.err` to a `JTextArea` easily but how do I do that for `System.in` ? Will I need to override `Inputstream` methods? Do I need to convert the `String` from `JTextArea` to byte array and then pass it to `InputStream`? Code examples would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently tried the same thing, here's my code:

```
class TexfFieldStreamer extends InputStream implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField tf;
    private String str = null;
    private int pos = 0;

    public TexfFieldStreamer(JTextField jtf) {
        tf = jtf;
    }

    //gets triggered everytime that "Enter" is pressed on the textfield
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        str = tf.getText() + "\n";
        pos = 0;
        tf.setText("");
        synchronized (this) {
            //maybe this should only notify() as multiple threads may
            //be waiting for input and they would now race for input
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int read() {
        //test if the available input has reached its end
        //and the EOS should be returned 
        if(str != null && pos == str.length()){
            str =null;
            //this is supposed to return -1 on "end of stream"
            //but I'm having a hard time locating the constant
            return java.io.StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF;
        }
        //no input available, block until more is available because that's
        //the behavior specified in the Javadocs
        while (str == null || pos >= str.length()) {
            try {
                //according to the docs read() should block until new input is available
                synchronized (this) {
                    this.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //read an additional character, return it and increment the index
        return str.charAt(pos++);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
    JTextField tf = new JTextField();
    TextFieldStreamer ts = new TextFieldStreamer(tf);
    //maybe this next line should be done in the TextFieldStreamer ctor
    //but that would cause a "leak a this from the ctor" warning
    tf.addActionListener(ts);

    System.setIn(ts);
```

Has been a while since I coded Java so I may not be up-to-date with the patterns. You should probably also overload `int available()` but my example just consists of the bare minimum to make it work with a `BufferedReader`s `readLine()` function.

**Edit:** For this to work for a `JTextField` you have to use `implements KeyListener` instead of `implements ActionListener` and then use `addKeyListener(...)` on your TextArea. The function that you need instead of `actionPerformed(...)` is `public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)` and then you have to test for `if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_ENTER)` and instead of using the whole text you just use a substring from the last line before the cursor with

```
//ignores the special case of an empty line
//so a test for \n before the Caret or the Caret still being at 0 is necessary
int endpos = tf.getCaret().getMark();
int startpos = tf.getText().substring(0, endpos-1).lastIndexOf('\n')+1;
```

for the input string. Because otherwise you would read the whole TextArea every time you press enter.

Comment: Cool Ill just have to change it so it takes last line of JTextArea. Thanks a lot

Comment: @latusaki well, not quite you'd have to modify it a little more, since the `JTextArea` doesn't generate `ActionEvent`s afaik. You could either make an unrelated button and add the action listener to that or override the `JTextArea` and catch the key-events to look out for `Ctrl-Enter` or something similar and then trigger the `ActionEvent` yourself.

Comment: read method is not getting called for some reason while testing with textfield.

Comment: @latusaki the `read()` is only supposed to be called when someone actually calls `System.in.read()` or if you wrap it in a `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))` and call `readLine()` it doesn't get called by itself and why would it?

Comment: I am still experimenting but what I want is when hitting enter the text goes to InputStream as it would on terminal

Comment: @latusaki well if you use System.in then you can only enter something when the program actually calls read() otherwise it stores it in a buffer which is the TextArea in your case. Also, I already told you that the `JTextArea` does not generate an ActionEvent upon pressing enter therefore my code won't work with a `JTextArea` as is. edit: My bad, I mean `JTextArea` of course

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7569/discussion-between-latusaki-and-petert)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own implementation of an `InputStream` that takes its input from whatever Swing component you want… basically have a buffer that you copy text to from your Swing component and that serves as a source for the `InputStream` (which of course needs to block if no input is available).