# Java redirecting System.in - InputStream.read called but nothing "returned"

Tags: java, inputstream, system.in

So I'm trying to redirect a textbox to System.in. I've seen this thread [Redirect System.in to swing component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244108/redirect-system-in-to-swing-component) , and seem to have everything working:

```
private class SystemIn extends InputStream {

    @Override
    public int read() {
        int x = GUIConsole.this.read();
        System.out.println("Read called: returning " + x);
        return x;
    }

}
```

The reads seem to be executing properly: I have a helper

```
public static String readLine(String msg) {
    String input = "";
    InputStreamReader converter = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(converter);

    while (input.length() == 0) {
        try {
            print(msg);
            input = in.readLine().trim();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            //
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

And I call

```
String in3 = SimpleConsole.readLine("Enter text: ");
System.out.println("You said: " + in3);
```

So the `"Read called: returning #"` is printed. I get the proper character codes followed by the final -1 when I call something. The read method blocks until input is ready, as the docs specify.

However, I only get the `"Read called..."` messages, and the next line (`"You said...`") never executes (it's stuck still reading). I can't for my life figure out what the problem is - If you want to see more code (although I think the `"Read called..."` messages show it's doing the right thing) just let me know.

Is there something else I should do to be able to call `readLine` and get the input from a textbox? I also tried overriding the other methods in inputstream without luck (again, the `read` method is executing properly)

Answer (score 1):

Agh, as usual, I find the answer soon after I post a question (and I say this every time too). Anyways, in case someone else is looking for this:

When reading/implementing the inputstream, make sure the last call returns the newline char 
`\n'` (followed by -1). Because if you're readline a **line** it waits for that last newline feed.

So for me, I append the text from a textfield *plus* a newline character. Now it works, the program finishes reading and printing the final message.

Comment: Looks like SO is your rubber duck debugger. (-: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging